# Prove that the derived set of a closed is closed

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $A \subset \mathbb{R}$. Then derived set of $A$, denoted by $A^{\prime}$, is the set of all accumulation points of $A$.

Prove that the derived set of a closed set is closed.

Attempt: Suppose $A$ is a closed set. Then we have $A=A^{\prime}$. Hence, $A^{\prime}$ is closed by equality.

Is this correct? It seems 'too good to be true'.

Comment: In general there is no need for every point of $A$ to be a limit point. You definitely have $A^{\prime} \subset A$ but not equality.

Comment: If $A=(0,1)$, then $A^{\prime}=[0,1]$. Wouldn't this contradict with what you state above?

Comment: I don't think that $(0,1)$ is closed (at least not in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: Good point, @Gage. I missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ is closed in our space $X$ and then consider $A^{\prime}$ the set of all limit points of $A$. Because $A$ is closed we have that $A = A \cup A^{\prime}$ and therefore $A^{\prime} \subset A$. Now if $x$ is an element of $X \backslash A^{\prime}$ then (by definition) we know that $x$ is not a limit point of $A$. Now that means there is some neighborhood $O_x$ such that $O_x \cap A \backslash \{x\} = \emptyset$. If we then remember that $x \not \in A^{\prime}$ then we have that $O_x \cap A^{\prime} = \emptyset$. Therefore $X \backslash A^{\prime}$  is open and $A^{\prime}$ is closed