# Derived set is closed for any set $A$

Tags: general-topology

I know that the derived set of $A$ is closed if $A$ is closed (as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1006918/758031)), but I am having a lot of trouble deciding whether $A'$ is closed for any given set $A$.
**My work so far:** I know that $A'$ is closed iff $\forall x \in (A')^C$ I can find $U$, $x\in U$ so that $U \cap(A')=\emptyset$
I want to get RHS in order to get that $A'$ is closed. I know that $x \in (A')^C \Longleftrightarrow \exists B$, $x \in B$ so that $(B \cap A)\backslash \{x \} = \emptyset$. I want to see that this $B$ is the $U$ I am looking for, but I don't know how to do this. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prove it, since it is not true. Suppose that $X=\{0,1\}$, endowed with the trivial topology. Then $\{0\}'=\{1\}$, but $\{1\}$ is not a closed set.

Comment: What is the "trivial topology" in $X$?

Comment: It's the topology which consists only of $\emptyset$ and $X$.

Comment: also called the indiscrete topology